# After upgrading ASA, client VPN failing from site with active LAN to LAN tunnel

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, ipsec

After upgrading our ASAs from 9.1(1) to newer versions, users were no longer able to connect using native IPsec VPN client software when inside of an office network.  From outside networks it still worked just fine.

The office networks have established VPN tunnels covering the IP range that the user's system falls under, but the workflow is to VPN in to gain access to restricted resources.

We verified that disconnecting the LAN to LAN IPsec tunnel to the office allowed the client to connect in successfully.

When debugging the connection attempt's IKE and IPsec, a log entry shows why this is failing:

```
Skipping dynamic map OUTSIDE_DYN_MAP sequence 100: cannot match peerless map when peer found in previous map entry.
```

That log entry led to several reports of this issue ([1](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11954391/issue-remote-access-vpn), [2](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/12099546/ipsec-vpn-not-working-after-upgrade-847)) with information clarifying that this behavior was introduced as a security fix in CSCuc75090, but no real functional workarounds - just recommendations to use the established tunnel or NAT the users to a different address than the tunnel peering is happening over.

Is there an effective workaround to allow for client VPN from these locations again?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the device can be instructed to accept the client VPN connections from the peer that it already has an open tunnel with.

This is done by updating the dynamic map to include new entries with a configured peer address.

So, with this existing configuration accepting a dynamic connection from any address:

```
crypto map vpnmap 10 match address peer_acl
crypto map vpnmap 10 set peer 192.0.2.15
crypto map vpnmap 10 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-SHA1
crypto map vpnmap 65500 ipsec-isakmp dynamic OUTSIDE_DYN_MAP
crypto dynamic-map OUTSIDE_DYN_MAP 100 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA
crypto dynamic-map OUTSIDE_DYN_MAP 100 set security-association lifetime seconds 86400
crypto dynamic-map OUTSIDE_DYN_MAP 100 set reverse-route
```

..the dynamic map can be edited to allow client VPN connections from the `192.0.2.15` peer:

```
crypto map vpnmap 10 match address peer_acl
crypto map vpnmap 10 set peer 192.0.2.15
crypto map vpnmap 10 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-SHA1
crypto map vpnmap 65500 ipsec-isakmp dynamic OUTSIDE_DYN_MAP
crypto dynamic-map OUTSIDE_DYN_MAP 10 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA
crypto dynamic-map OUTSIDE_DYN_MAP 10 set security-association lifetime seconds 86400
crypto dynamic-map OUTSIDE_DYN_MAP 10 set reverse-route
crypto dynamic-map OUTSIDE_DYN_MAP 10 set peer 192.0.2.15
crypto dynamic-map OUTSIDE_DYN_MAP 100 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA
crypto dynamic-map OUTSIDE_DYN_MAP 100 set security-association lifetime seconds 86400
crypto dynamic-map OUTSIDE_DYN_MAP 100 set reverse-route
```

..and client IPsec connections will now be allowed from `192.0.2.15` despite having an active LAN to LAN tunnel.